# Relation between eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $[e, x]$ is the eigenpair of the matrix $A$. Can $[e^m, x^m]$ be the corresponding eigenpair for $A^m$?

I know that $e^m$ can be the eigenvalue of $A^m$. I am wondering whether $x^m$ will be the corresponding eigenvector or not?

Comment: Whats a power of a vector?

Comment: consider using latex notation

Comment: new to this site not able to use the symbols for lambda and superscript...sorrry

Answer (score 1):

If $(\lambda,\pmb{x})$ is an eigenpair of $\pmb{A}$, then $(\lambda^n,\pmb{x})$ is an eigenpair of $\pmb{A}^n$, because $\pmb{A}^n \pmb{x} = \lambda \pmb{A}^{n-1}\pmb{x} = \lambda^2 \pmb{A}^{n-2}\pmb{x} =\ldots = \lambda^{n-1}\pmb{A}\pmb{x} = \lambda^{n}\pmb{x}$, giving $\pmb{A}^n \pmb{x}=\lambda^{n}\pmb{x}$

Comment: From your explanation it seems that x^m is not possible for A^m....right

Comment: What do you mean by x^m ????

Comment: I mean eigen vector raised to the power m..

Comment: and what does that mean ?

Comment: Forget that.  i would like to ask u one more question...  The question is

Comment: How many independent eigen vector are possible for two equal eigen values?